# Precalculate/Validate auto battle game outcome on client/server?

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer

All those idle/clicker hero games out there made me wonder how the server usually verifies the games where the player has no influence at all. I'm sure both clients would return the same result if no hacking found place but surely the server checks if both games where legit.

For anyone who don't know the games. You pick X heroes for your defending team and enlist yourself for PvP. These heroes have countless of levels, abilities and equipment. Now anyone who has a defensive team can attack other players defense. This battle will be played out in front of the player and in most games cannot be influenced at all. Another important factor is that the defending player does not have to be online and can watch it later.

Now the question is how can I have the exact same outcome of a battle on server and clients. I don't think I should bother with checking each move against the server and predicting other entities on the client but using random to precalculate the result on the server and can be used to play/replay on the clients too.

Afaik, a basic (not so random) random number generator would generate the same numbers in sequence on different devices. I am using java and a quick search gives the following:

*"If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers. In order to guarantee this property, particular algorithms are specified for the class Random. Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the class Random, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code. However, subclasses of class Random are permitted to use other algorithms, so long as they adhere to the general contracts for all the methods."*

So with that theory I could have a identical battle model for both clients and server. When a battle commences the server generates a seed and if both clients and the server use the same seed they should see the same outcome.

So the issue is getting all the methods run in the exact same order. So I need the game to run exactly the same on both devices regardless of speed and hickups. How would I do this?

- Making the game framerate independent would caus issues since then I need to interpolate a lot when there is a hickup on a device. And even then I can imagine a unit having a slightly different position which can cause a snowball effect.
- Making the game framerate dependent would solve this, both games now need an equal amount of frames/steps. But this can make the game feel "jaggy" if there are just some slight deviations in framerate.
- Other ideas?

Now the server is different. Obviously I do not need to simulate the entire battle to show it to anyone, I just need a win or a loss and perhaps some stats from the battle like damage done. If it's possible I just want to fetch the result and slam that straight into the database even before the players are past the battle loading screen. If I make the game framerate dependent, so it's just about steps, I could just loop trough the whole game on the server.

I know it's a somewhat broad question but I'm sure there is a good answer for the question stated in the title. Afterwards I can clean up my question.

Comment: I'm unsure how having _no_ user input would make it _more_ difficult to verify on a server? You don't have to simulate the battle at all on the client, the server just tells the client **"Hey, this unit went here at this time"** and then the client shows you that data. No simulation required.

Comment: @Charanor I'm very unsure about that too. I do know it's very different, at least to implement it correctly. So you say I just run the gameloop once on the server, when a unit changes behavior record it (like a key frame?). Then send those key frames to the client?

Comment: @Charanor I'm also unsure how you get the upvote. I know my question is long and people tend to not read. But as you can see in my own answer, to do what I want is different and difficult is only relative, once you know how to approach something it's not difficult anymore. You might want to reconsider your comment.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found an answer for my question. While searching for deterministic behaviour I came across implementing replay functionality. It's like I explained in the answer and deterministic was the word I'm looking for. It basically guarantees the same outcome because the steps will be the same on every machine. On the server it runs in a continues loop the game client needs to make sure it runs in a fixed time step.

-edit-
So as far as I understand now, to make a game deterministic everything should happen in the exact same order and in the exact same manner on each run/machine/device. A game loop simply tackles the first already, unless you randomly start calling methods with reflection. Also, if you use a deterministic `Random()` function you should seed it in the same way of every run obviously. And the starting state of the game should be exactly the same.

Now as for the manner in how functions behave they can defer if you are passing and using a delta time to it. Here is an example:

```
// normal frame (0.016s)
velocity.x * delta; //(0.016s) 
// laggy frame (0.054s)
velocity.x * delta; //(0.054s)
```

Even the slightest deviation in frame time can result in completely different behavior after just a couple of frames. A deterministic physics engine will time step already under the hood. There is a really easy way to fix this, all we need to do is pass in the exact same delta each frame and we are done. A fixed number like `0.016` for a 60fps game should do the trick already really well. But what if the device is severally lagging and going down to 10fps for a while? Then we see our game slow down 6 times, it's like we put in raw numbers for velocity and position without multiplying by the delta time. A simply fix would be to to have it run the update with the fixed delta 6 times. This of course still results in choppy visuals but at least the games speed will remain as intended.

Conclusion, if you do not need delta time then you most probably already have a deterministic game. Obviously you need the same seed if you use random and there should not be any black magic into how you call your functions. In that regard most games are already deterministic.

Now on to some code. I want to credit the [first article I found about creating replay functionality](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2029/developing_your_own_replay_system.php). Essentially my question is about this, I just did not realize it. All I need to do is run the simulation on the server to determine the win. Then whenever the client wants to watch it it should play exactly the same, as in a replay. The article goes in depth on the pro's and cons of deterministic replay functionality. [The code that got me started is almost 7 years old](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,24220.0) but still very up to date. It shows how to do a proper game loop and how to do a fixed time step. I am using LibGDX and thus I already have a game loop, I just need to bend it into a fixed time step.

```
// I am using my BaseScreen class for testing.
// It just sets up a view things like the batch and stage and my assets.
public class FixedStepScreen extends BaseScreen {

    // Calculate how much time between each tick.
    // If a frame takes double this time then 2 ticks will be processed.
    // And thus, this dictates the game speed.
    final double FPS = 60;
    final double STEP_TIME = 1000 / FPS;

    // The maximum amount of updates. If a device lags, it won't try to catch up in a single frame.
    final int MAX_STEPS_PER_FRAME = 4;

    // Time since last update tick.
    double previousTickTime;

    // Object for testing, simple sprite moving from left to right
    Player player;

    public FixedStepScreen(AssetManager assetManager,
                           SpriteBatch stageBatch,
                           GameClient gameClient) {
        super(assetManager, stageBatch, gameClient);

        //Set the tick time to the current time.
        previousTickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        player = new Player();
    }

    /**
     * This is the regular game loop in LibGDX. This represents a single frame and logic/draw
     * therefor goes synchronously by default in LibGDX.
     * @param delta
     */
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);

        // I simulated some very basic lag
        simulateLag();

        double currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int stepCount = 0;

        double myDelta = currentTime - previousTickTime;

        while ( currentTime - previousTickTime > STEP_TIME &&
                stepCount < MAX_STEPS_PER_FRAME) {

            step();
            // Since we did a tick we should add the tick .
            previousTickTime += STEP_TIME;
            stepCount++;
        }

        System.out.println("Frame took " + myDelta + "ms : " + stepCount + " steps processed this frame.");

        draw();
    }


    /**
     * All deterministic logic should go here. This gets called more often.
     */
    protected void step() {

/*       STEP_TIME is the delta in this case. it is fixed obviously so each step the object will
         move and act based on the same time. Passing this to a none deterministic physics engine
         as the delta will therefor make it deterministic as even a slight variation of time between
         different runs or devices can have huge impact on the calculated physics.*/

        player.step(STEP_TIME);
    }

    // -- I already separated logic(Update) and rendering(draw) in the BaseScreen. --

    /**
     * None deterministic logic, depending on your game this could be a camera, animations or
     * anything you don't need to be deterministic and has no effect on other deterministic elements.
     * @param delta
     */
    @Override
    protected void update(float delta) {
        super.update(delta);

        // If an object has non deterministic it should not use the deterministic step() function
        // for obvious performance reasons.
        player.update(delta);
    }

    /**
     * Just draw normally and let the tick functionality handle the deterministic logic.
     * draw() will be called after all logic from step() and update() is processed.
     */
    @Override
    protected void draw() {
        super.draw();
        spriteBatch.begin();

        player.draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Generates some random lag
     */
    private void simulateLag() {
        if (random.nextInt(100) < 50) {

            double frameLag = STEP_TIME * (random.nextDouble() * 2);

            System.out.println("Artificial lag: " + frameLag + "ms.");

            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)frameLag);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I do not need to add all the fancy stuff like skipping halfway through the "replay", you can look that up in the first article. All I need to do is create a loop on the server and let the deterministic steps run with the exact same `STEP_TIME` as the client. This will quickly generate an outcome, in my case I can store the all the results I need straight into the database.

Disclaimer:
This is still the theory, partly tested and I still need to setup the whole client/server functionality for this. All I can say is "this should work", and we all know here what will happen when you hear that :). I will update.

Comment: Could someone please tell me why I am getting downvotes? I'm all ok with removing and not posting my efforts to get a sync between server and clients without the need of running all of them at the same time.